# Php line breaks for hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

Would like to have hyperlink in two lines. with present code they are one besides the other

```
<a href='<?php echo ( site_url('inout/inoutverify')?>'>Stock Verification</a> |
<a href='<?php echo site_url('inout/pricehistory')?>'>Price Change History</a> |
```

Comment: breaks... how? what did you see? what is the expected result?

Comment: This is absolutely not a PHP issue, but one of HTML/CSS.

Comment: for me _"one below the other"_ and _"two lines"_ is the same. ?

Comment: Use `<br>` tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: oh right, a `<br>` can solve the issue. i missed the `|` and *with present code they are one besides the other*.

Comment: Thanks <br> did work

Comment: I really want to ask why there are a lot of downvotes in this very reasonable question. It has a straightforward question with code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('inout/inoutverify');?>">Stock Verification</a> |
<a href="<?php echo site_url('inout/pricehistory'); ?> ">Price Change History</a> |
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` tags are displayed inline.

You can display them as blocks `display: block;`

`a {display: block;}`

This will do it for all `a` tags so append/prepend a class

`<a class='displayBlock' href='<?php echo ( site_url('inout/inoutverify')?>'>Stock Verification</a>`

`a.displayBlock {display: block;}`